# Inheriting from fstream

Tags: c++, inheritance, fstream

I am writing a class to provide various IO operations that will be used for reading and writing to a file.  I am currently trying to inherit from fstream rather then create my own file open, close, etc functions.  Currently my sample code below has no functions added, I simply open the write to it and close it.   However the test code is unable to successfully open the file when exicuted.  I will be adding additional code I can properly inherit from fstream.  I get no compiler warnings or errors with this code using g++, and it runs without crashing however I get the "Unable to open file" message, proving the open was not successful.

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    FileParser myFileParser;

    myFileParser.open("c:\test.txt"); 
  if (myFileParser.is_open())
  {
    myFileParser << "This is a line.\n";
    myFileParser << "This is another line.\n";
    myFileParser.close();
  }
  else
  {
    cout << "Unable to open file\r\n";
  }

  myFileParser.close();

    return 0;
}

#pragma once
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

class FileParser: public fstream 
{
    public:
        FileParser(void);
        virtual ~FileParser(void);

    private:
};

#include "FileParser.h"

FileParser::FileParser(void)
{
}

FileParser::~FileParser(void)
{
}
```

Any help with this issue would be appreciated.

---

The issue has now been resolved, thanks for the support.

Regards

Comment: In addition to what @WhozCraig has said, you have chosen to extend perhaps the worst set of classes ever designed. Documentation on how to actually do so is non-existent. I tried this years ago to provide a socket stream class. It took forever to even figure out exactly what to do and where the actual I/O takes place. Compared to that, writing the sockets part was trivial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To address your immediate problems:

1. You forgot to escape the backslash:

   `myFileParser.open("c:\\test.txt");`
2. From the file path, Im guessing you are on windows, you will probably get a "permission denied" as you do not have permissions opening a file at that location (this is true for Vista and up).

Comment: Thank you, the problem was permissions in windows, I had figured writing to C:\ would avoid that problem, but I was wrong.  I have the code changed to `myFileParser.open("test.txt"); `, and the file is generated by with no text in it.  I did the same test using a standard fstream file and it works.  This would support the two other comments.

Comment: @rutri: You need to open in append mode: `myFileParser.open("test.txt", std::ios::app);`

Comment: I had already caught that one, I actually opened it as `myFileParser.open("test.txt", ios::out|ios::app);` and it has no effect, I also deleted the file watched it get recreated with nothing inside.

Comment: It turns out that I had another error, I have been calling open twice.  The issue was resolved after removing the second open.  Thanks!